# chrome crashes but strace chrome doesn't

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Chromedriver is started with `xvfb-run chromedriver --disable-dev-shm-usage --enable-chrome-logs --allowed-ips=127.0.0.1`.

Here's what I know:

```
bash-4.2# chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839})
bash-4.2# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 110.0.5481.77
bash-4.2# curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -d '{"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--no-sandbox","--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome/2","--data-path=/tmp/chrome/3","--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/chrome/4","--no-zygote","--disable-dev-shm-usage","--disable-gpu","--single-process"]}}],"alwaysMatch":{"browserName":"chrome","pageLoadStrategy":"none"}}}'  http://localhost:9515/session
{"value":{"error":"disconnected","message":"disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer\n  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)\n  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.77)","stacktrace":"#0 0x562dfdcfad93 \u003Cunknown>\n#1 0x562dfdac92d7 \u003Cunknown>\n#2 0x562dfdab36d3 \u003Cunknown>\n#3 0x562dfdab1ee2 \u003Cunknown>\n#4 0x562dfdab2682 \u003Cunknown>\n#5 0x562dfdab25d4 \u003Cunknown>\n#6 0x562dfdaa4170 \u003Cunknown>\n#7 0x562dfdaa39c0 \u003Cunknown>\n#8 0x562dfdaa2d35 \u003Cunknown>\n#9 0x562dfdb32653 \u003Cunknown>\n#10 0x562dfdb29353 \u003Cunknown>\n#11 0x562dfdaf8e40 \u003Cunknown>\n#12 0x562dfdafa038 \u003Cunknown>\n#13 0x562dfdd4e8be \u003Cunknown>\n#14 0x562dfdd528f0 \u003Cunknown>\n#15 0x562dfdd32f90 \u003Cunknown>\n#16 0x562dfdd53b7d \u003Cunknown>\n#17 0x562dfdd24578 \u003Cunknown>\n#18 0x562dfdd78348 \u003Cunknown>\n#19 0x562dfdd784d6 \u003Cunknown>\n#20 0x562dfdd92341 \u003Cunknown>\n#21 0x7fa628df844b start_thread\n"}}
```

Looking into the chromedriver verbose logs, Chrome was happily sitting at a new tab and then things went haywire:

```
[1675906446.284][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Target.getTargets (id=1) (session_id=) browser {
   "targetInfos": [ {
      "attached": false,
      "browserContextId": "D38C850EC0824ADB75AD7FE1597FE262",
      "canAccessOpener": false,
      "targetId": "1AFD8F644C4F1088FA776DA626B4F18D",
      "title": "New Tab",
      "type": "page",
      "url": "chrome://newtab/"
   } ]
}
[1675906446.284][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Target.attachToTarget (id=2) (session_id=) browser {
   "flatten": true,
   "targetId": "1AFD8F644C4F1088FA776DA626B4F18D"
}
[0209/013406.300892:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0209/013406.300954:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1675906446.312][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
```

We know the cpufreq thing is a red herring as it is coming from the crash reporter.

But here's the insane catch: if I replace the chrome binary with

```
cat /opt/google/chrome/chrome
#!/bin/bash
strace -o /tmp/strace -f /opt/google/chrome/chrome-binary "$@"
```

Then it *works*. If I remove the `strace` and the keep the shell script it crashes again. Also tried Chrome 98 and 102, they crash just the same.

Here is the payload from above nicely formatted:

```
{
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "goog:chromeOptions": {
          "args": [
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome/2",
            "--data-path=/tmp/chrome/3",
            "--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/chrome/4",
            "--no-zygote",
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--single-process"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "alwaysMatch": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "pageLoadStrategy": "none"
    }
  }
}
```

note I added `pageLoadStrategy` after the error surfaced and it doesn't matter -- but I wanted to show I've tried.

This is some sort of CentOS, a Dockerfile based on `public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2` running locally (it fails the same on AWS Lambda). Here's how:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2
COPY chrome-deps.txt /tmp/
RUN yum install -q -y $(cat /tmp/chrome-deps.txt) https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
COPY install-chrome.sh /tmp/
RUN /usr/bin/bash /tmp/install-chrome.sh
```

The requirements is probably utter overkill to spell out but:

```
acl adwaita-cursor-theme adwaita-icon-theme alsa-lib at-spi2-atk at-spi2-core
atk avahi-libs cairo cairo-gobject colord-libs cryptsetup-libs cups-libs dbus
dbus-libs dconf desktop-file-utils device-mapper device-mapper-libs elfutils-default-yama-scope
elfutils-libs emacs-filesystem fribidi gdk-pixbuf2 glib-networking gnutls graphite2
gsettings-desktop-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache gtk3 harfbuzz hicolor-icon-theme hwdata jasper-libs
jbigkit-libs json-glib kmod kmod-libs lcms2 libX11 libX11-common libXau libXcomposite libXcursor libXdamage
libXext libXfixes libXft libXi libXinerama libXrandr libXrender libXtst libXxf86vm libdrm libepoxy
liberation-fonts liberation-fonts-common liberation-mono-fonts liberation-narrow-fonts liberation-sans-fonts
liberation-serif-fonts libfdisk libglvnd libglvnd-egl libglvnd-glx libgusb libidn libjpeg-turbo libmodman
libpciaccess libproxy libsemanage libsmartcols libsoup libthai libtiff libusbx libutempter libwayland-client
libwayland-cursor libwayland-egl libwayland-server libxcb libxkbcommon libxshmfence lz4 mesa-libEGL mesa-libGL
mesa-libgbm mesa-libglapi nettle pango pixman qrencode-libs rest shadow-utils systemd systemd-libs trousers ustr
util-linux vulkan vulkan-filesystem wget which xdg-utils xkeyboard-config 
xorg-x11-server-Xvfb unzip
```

the install script is not much:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

CHROMEVERSION=$(curl -s https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)
curl -s https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEVERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip > /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. downloaded `chromium.br` from https://github.com/Sparticuz/chrome-aws-lambda/blob/2fb71eb0ca2e08292973efe3ca59182debbbffc8/bin/chromium.br while this repo is deprecated, the Chromium 110 from the new repo doesn't seem to work?
2. `brotli -d chromium.br`
3. In `Dockerfile`, `COPY chromium /usr/bin/google-chrome`
4. `CHROMEVERSION=$(curl -s https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_106.0.5249)`

I still have no idea what's going on but I will take it. For the next few years being stuck on Chromium 106 is fine.